# Failed:{"success":false,"code":"INTERNAL_SECURITY_BLOCK",message":"Internal Security Block","data":{}}

Tags: android, phonepe, phonepepaymentsdk

**This is my function:**

```
private void payUsingPhonePe() throws PhonePeInitException {
    String MERCHANT_ID = "<hidden>";
    String salt = "<hidden>";
    String apiEndPoint = "/pg/v1/pay";
    PhonePe.init(Checkout.this, PhonePeEnvironment.RELEASE, MERCHANT_ID, "<hidden>");
    HashMap<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("merchantId", MERCHANT_ID);
    data.put("merchantTransactionId", orderId);
    data.put("merchantUserId", custID);
    data.put("amount", total * 100);
    data.put("mobileNumber", phone);
    data.put("callbackUrl", "https://webhook.site/callback-url");
    HashMap<String, Object> paymentInstrument = new HashMap<>();
    paymentInstrument.put("type", "UPI_INTENT");
    paymentInstrument.put("targetApp", "com.phonepe.app");
    data.put("paymentInstrument", paymentInstrument);
    HashMap<String, Object> deviceContext = new HashMap<>();
    deviceContext.put("deviceOS", "ANDROID");
    data.put("deviceContext", deviceContext);
    String payloadBase64 = convertDataToBase64(data);
    String checksum = generateChecksum(payloadBase64, apiEndPoint, salt);
    B2BPGRequest b2BPGRequest = new B2BPGRequestBuilder()
            .setData(Objects.requireNonNull(payloadBase64))
            .setChecksum(Objects.requireNonNull(checksum))
            .setUrl(apiEndPoint)
            .build();
    List<UPIApplicationInfo> upiApps = PhonePe.getUpiApps();
    startActivityForResult(PhonePe.getImplicitIntent(this, b2BPGRequest, upiApps.toString()), 777);
}
```

**This is another function:**

```
public static String convertDataToBase64(HashMap<String, Object> data) {
    try {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(data);
        byte[] base64Bytes = Base64.encode(jsonString.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        return new String(base64Bytes);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

**This is another function:**

```
public static String generateChecksum(String payloadBase64, String apiEndPoint, String salt) {
    try {
        String dataToHash = payloadBase64 + apiEndPoint + salt;
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.update(dataToHash.getBytes());
        byte[] byteData = md.digest();
        StringBuilder checksumBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : byteData) {
            checksumBuilder.append(String.format("%02x", b));
        }
        return checksumBuilder + "###1";
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

**This is onActivityResult:**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    String result = null;
    if (data != null) {
        result = data.getStringExtra("key_txn_result");
        if (data.getExtras() != null && data.getExtras().keySet().size() > 0) {
            Log.i(TAG, "result has extras");
            for (String key : data.getExtras().keySet()) {
                Log.i(TAG, key + " = " + data.getExtras().get(key));
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "result has 0 extras");
        }
    }
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Result: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        if (requestCode == 777 && data != null && data.getExtras().containsKey("key_error_result"))
            result = data.getStringExtra("key_error_result");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I am not able to make payment using PhonePe gateway. I tried all the things and now I am fed up with all this. Do anyone have a solution to this issue. Please let me know then. I am getting the below error in toast:

Failed:{"success":false,"code":"INTERNAL_SECURITY_BLOCK",message":"Internal Security Block","data":{}}

Answer (score 0):

us bro us

we're encountering the same issue, this error code is not mentioned in the PhonePe docs!

Comment: As it's currently written, your answer is not actually answering the question and contains phrases that are not relevant to the context of the question. Please edit your answer. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).